# Sort pagerank values of graph-tool vertices

Tags: python, pagerank, graph-tool

I have a directed graph-tool graph `g`. I also have already calculated the pagerank for each vertex in the graph using `graph_tool.centrality.pagerank` as shown below.

```py
v_pr = g.new_vertex_property('float')
pr = pagerank(u, prop=v_pr)
u.vp['vertex_pagerank'] = v_pr
```

From here, I can access the pagerank value of a vertex given its index.

What I want to do, however, is to extract, say, the top 10 vertices of the graph in terms of their pagerank values.

Is there a quick way to do this on `graph-tool`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `g` is our graph and that we we have already computed our PageRank values and stored them in `u.vp['vertex_pagerank']`, we can convert the vertex property to a list of (`vertex_index`, `pagerank_value`) tuples

```py
vertex_pagerank_list = [(v, u.vp['vertex_pagerank'][v]) for v in u.vertices()]
```

We can then sort the list based on `pagerank_value` in descending order

```
vertex_pagerank_list.sort(key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
```

To extract the top 10 vertices:

```
top_10_vertices = vertex_pagerank_list[:10]

# Print the top 10 vertices and their PageRank values
for vertex, pr_value in top_10_vertices:
print(f"Vertex: {int(vertex)}, PageRank: {pr_value}")
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to graph-tool and was wondering about a similar problem. Don't know how efficient my solution is, but for what it's worth I ended up doing it like this:

```
vertices_by_rank = sorted(u.vertices(), key=lambda v: pr[v], reverse=True)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).